# Error: spawn unzip ENOENT event.js:174

Tags: npm

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn unzip ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Getting this error for a while, tried all possible solutions but ended up screwing things more. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Another finding when I am running echo $PATH in my script it is displaying different path variables a subset of what I can see on my terminal running the same command.

Comment: Is the `unzip` package installed on your system? Outside of node.js, what is the output of `type -a unzip`?

Comment: Its outside the system. I am trying to run a script to get geo data using some libraries.